# Fragment Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some trouble with fragment I got an error that says:

```
Binary XML file line #2 Error: inflating class fragment.
Cause by: Java.lan.NullPointerException: name == null
```

This is my binary file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:name="com.livetrekker.fragments.WelcomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then my FragmentActivity:

```
public class SetupWizard extends FragmentActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wizardsetup);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        WelcomeFragment wf = new WelcomeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_content, wf);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And Finally my fragment:

```
Public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcomelivetrekker,container, false);
    }
}
```

I have imported the Android.support.v4.app.Fragment to both of my file and check out on the internet, but none of the solution is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity_wizardsetup.xml should look something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Then your fragment_content.xml should look something to this effect:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I believe that should fix it... in my code i use a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) rather than FragmentTransaction or FragmentManager... but i think fixing the xml up will work...

Comment: it works thanks. Just a small mistake it's <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager insteand of <android.support.v4.view.ViewPage

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I figured I'd answer this anyway, since the solution here did not work for me, but the problem was the same.

Exception was on inflating the fragment, because name was null.
The fragment must have the following field:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Source [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key).